How to get the top token holders? Python
What is the best way to get information about wallets that hold a certain token that is owned by SPL program?
I am programming in python using solana.py, tried using get_program_accounts() from Async API Client, but I keep getting a 401 Gone error if my memory serves me correctly. I've also tried changing the RPC, and tried adding different filters, but it doesn't help.
I know there is get_largest_accounts(), but I need more than 20 accounts.
Are there any other ways how this can be done for free, without buying for example the same solscan api?

Unfortunately, outside of looking at all the accounts in batches or using getTokenLargestAccounts https://solana.com/docs/rpc/http/gettokenlargestaccounts, there is no easy free solution.

I would suggest u to use solathon , as it a better and more maintained version of Solana python SDK.
They have all the same methods as Solana.py.
U can use get_program_accounts or get_token_account_balance methods to get token balances for a particular token mint.
